# NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am trying to store the path of a script into a variable using:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

However, it keeps returning a `name '__file__' is not defined` error.

```
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding extra information in the comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pretty sure you are running this in a terminal in the interactive Python as it is the only place (I'm aware of) to not have `__file__`.

Try it in the actual script. This should work.

Answer (score 6):

I run into this when **testing / debugging** classes in Spyder (nearly every day).  The fix is easy: define the `__file__` variable to the name of the py module you are testing.

In the interpreter type:

```
__file__ = 'modulename.py'
```

Then run the script again.  This method has never caused an issue for me.

Comment: This isn't very maintainable. If you rename the module, your code will likely break. The variable shouldn't need to be defined manually

Comment: @byxor - I have not experienced this to be true.  Renaming `__file__` **only renames for that instance**.  When running the script properly from the CLI (not debugging) it is auto assigned and all is well.  I use this time and time again - never had an issue.

Comment: This is a nice hack to explore and test code that includes "os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))".  Thank you.